# Uncompress a compressed data returned from a url in php

Tags: php, curl, gzip, compression

```
<php

$location = "";
        $ch = curl_init($location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $r = mb_convert_encoding($r, 'ISO-8859-1', 'utf-8');
        gzuncompress($r);
?>
```

My code retun a  Warning: gzuncompress(): data error in...
So how to can I decompress from compressed data though a url as the above. Thank for help.

Comment: I think there is really something wrong with the response data you're trying to decompress. Saving payload in a file and uncompress it with gzip results in: gzip: data.gz: not in gzip format. Right compression, encoding, ... ?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of the data returned from that URL.

Comment: Exactly, data returned from url in gzip format with encoding ISO-8859-1 and it decompressed in C#.net but in php with my code occured problem as the above.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inordinate number of `0xc2` and `0xc3` byte values in the data, and no other values above `0xbf`.  The original binary data seems to have been encoded somehow with those as escapes for the disallowed values.

*Update:*

The escapes can be processed to convert it to a valid gzip stream.  For each `0xc2` encountered, discard the `0xc2` and take the next byte as-is.  For each `0xc3` encountered, discard the `0xc3` and add `0x40` to the next byte.

*Update 2:*

For illustration, here is some simple php code that does the transformation on the data returned by the URL in the question, in place, resulting in a valid gzip stream (the `substr()` is optional):

```
        for ($i = $j = 0; $i < strlen($r); $i++, $j++)
            if (ord($r[$i]) == 194 && $i + 1 < strlen($r))
                $r[$j] = $r[++$i];
            else if (ord($r[$i]) == 195 && $i + 1 < strlen($r))
                $r[$j] = chr(ord($r[++$i]) + 64);
            else if ($i != $j)
                $r[$j] = $r[$i];
        $r = substr($r, 0, $j);
        echo gzdecode($r);
```

Note that you need to use `gzdeocde()`, not `gzuncompress()`.  `gzdecode()` decompresses gzip streams, whereas `gzuncompress()` decompresses zlib streams.

Comment: No, still  Warning: gzuncompress(): data error ... a

Comment: You need to not do another conversion, e.g. `mb_convert_encoding`, and you need to use `gzdecode()`, not `gzuncompress()`.

Comment: Yes, Mark Adler. Really , I thank you very much. I want to ask you why did appearance 0xc2 and 0xc3 byte values in the data ? Maybe, encoding ISO-8859-1 was causing that problem?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with character sets.  It appears that the server is coding the data as you might a URI, which uses those escape characters.